# DataTables not initialising twice on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to use DataTables twice on two different modals, the problem I'm having is the second modal that opens the DataTable isn't being initialised?

**CodePen of the process -**

http://codepen.io/kieronapple/pen/WwzrgP

**How it should work -**

1. First modal opens first DataTables initialises
2. Press manage on the first modal, second modal opens. But DataTables doesn't initialise?

**Function to initialise both tables**

```
function getValidTags(type){
    var ruleID = $('.ruleID').val();

    switch(type){
        case "validTags":
          var table = $('.valid-tags').DataTable({
              "ajax": {
                  "url": "/ajax/getValidTags.php",
                  "type": "POST",
                  "data": {
                    ruleID: ruleID,
                    type: type
                  },
              },
              "columnDefs": [{
                 "targets": 2,
                 "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                            return '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm manageAutofixes" type="button">Manage</button> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteValid">Delete</button>';          
                 }
              }],
              destroy: true     
          });
        break;

        case "autofixes":
        alert('hi');
          var table2 = $('.autofixes-table').DataTable({
              "ajax": {
                  "url": "/ajax/getValidTags.php",
                  "type": "POST",
                  "data": {
                    ruleID: ruleID,
                    type: type
                  },
              },
              "columnDefs": [{
                 "targets": 2,
                 "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                            return '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm manageAutofixes" type="button">Manage</button>';          
                 }
              }],
              destroy: true     
          });
        break;
    }
}
```

**Function to action first DataTable**

```
$('input[class="val_list"]').click(function() {
    $('.ruleID').val($('#mongoid').val());          
    $('.validation-list-modal').modal('show');      
    $('.validTagsTable').empty();
    if ($('.val_list').is(':checked')) {
      $(".tags, .tm-input, .new-tag, .allow_null_div, #null-label, .auto-fix").show();
    }
    getValidTags('validTags');
});
```

**Function to action second DataTable**

```
$('.valid-tags').on('click', '.manageAutofixes', function(){
    $('.autofixes-modal').modal('show');   
    getValidTags('autofixes');           
})
```

Comment: Check if any table has both `valid-tags` and `autofixes-table` classes. Also destroy:true -- is it needed?

Comment: @sid Both tables have unique classes, also destroy is needed as the table will be opened and closed constantly :)

Comment: Has this been resolved? I have the same problem